# How to use id_rsa.pub file with JSch

Tags: java, ssh, sftp, jsch, private-key

I am facing problem to connect a remote SFTP server using JSch(). I don't have any access or information about the remote server to connect except a **id_rsa.pub** file and the **hostname** and the **host_ip_address**. And the key in that file is registered as authorized key in the remote server. As I am able to login to the remote server from shell.

```
sftp -o BindAddress=SOME_IP_ADDRRESS myUserName@HOST_IP_ADDR
```

Its working fine. But when I am trying the same with JSch, its not working. What I have done is:

1. I have created a private key from the public key available in id_rsa.pub file using ssh keygen.
2. The public key format is

   **`ssh-rsa AA.... == someuser@something.com`**
3. The private key I generated from keygen is like

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

```
  KIOPU.....
```

-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

I am using this private key file with my `session.addIdentity(private_key_file_path);`

But it is giving auth_failure exception , am I doing something wrong

The code is:

```
/* KEY_FILE_NAME = is a file with rsa public key */
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(KEY_FILE_NAME).getFile());
JSch jsch = new JSch();
jsch.addIdentity(file.getAbsolutePath());
Properties hash = new Properties();
hash.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
logger.debug("SSh Server Host name >>" + SSH_SERVER_HOST_NAME + " || User Name >>" +  SSH_SERVER_USER_NAME);

session = jsch.getSession(SSH_SERVER_USER_NAME, SSH_SERVER_HOST_NAME);
UserInfo ui = new MyUserInfo();
session.setUserInfo(ui);
session.setConfig(hash);
session.setPort(22);
session.setTimeout(45000);
session.setSocketFactory(new SocketFactory() 
{
    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;

    public InputStream getInputStream(Socket socket) throws IOException 
    {
        if (in == null)
            in = socket.getInputStream();
        return in;
    }

    public OutputStream getOutputStream(Socket socket) throws IOException 
    {
        if (out == null)
            out = socket.getOutputStream();
        return out;
    }

    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException, UnknownHostException 
    {
       // The IP Addresses are changed ....
       // using the original IP in my code
        byte[] remoteIpAddr = new byte[] { (byte) 11,(byte) 11, 11, 11 }; 
        byte[] localIpAddr = new byte[] { 55, 55, 55, 55 };

        InetAddress remoteIp = InetAddress.getByAddress(remoteIpAddr);
        InetAddress localIp = InetAddress.getByAddress(localIpAddr);

        logger.debug("remoteIp >>" + remoteIp.toString());
        logger.debug("localIp >>" + localIp.toString());
        Socket socket = new Socket(remoteIp, 22, localIp, 0);
        logger.debug("socket created >> " + socket.toString());
        return socket;
    }
});
session.connect();
```

Please help, what I am doing wrong...

Comment: How do you use the key with command-line `ssh`? How did you "created a private key from the public key"? It does not make sense.

Comment: Hi Martin : Thanks a lot for your help, now my code is working fine.. the mistake I have made that I was using the wrong private key file. The previous code is working fine. Just chnage the key content and chane the private key file name from id_rsa.pub to id_rsa.

Comment: OK, please delete this question then.

Comment: @ArpanDas you created a private key from the public key? how come? It should be other way around.